# Talend DI V8 : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, sql-server, driver, pom.xml, talend

I've encountered an issue with a component in Talend DI V8. I recently transitioned from Talend V7 to Talend V8 locally and need to migrate my old job to this new version due to a database change.

In Talend V7, my job successfully connects to the SQL Server database and executes without issues. However, when I attempt to run the job in Talend V8, I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at interfaces...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 19 more
```

Before running my job, I had to locate and integrate the `sqljdbc41-6.0.8112.jar` driver for my `tDBConnection` component.

Could this be a driver issue? Or might I need to make modifications in my POM files or dependencies?

I've attempted to use different drivers, but they didn't seem to resolve the problem. I'm considering making changes to my POM files.

Comment: *i have this :* [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly. Try adding JAXB dependency to [your pom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

[Talend 8](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/data-catalog-installation-and-upgrade-guide-windows/compatible-java-runtime-environments) supports and recommends Java 11, with some caveats in specific cases stated in the documentation. The `javax.xml.bind` module was removed starting with Java 11.

You have to add it manually as a dependency in your POM.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for yoyr answer. I will try this

Comment: @Max Let me know if it works or not!